# How to get a page url segment on wordpress?

Tags: urls, page-template, parameter

I've created a regular wordpress page named "user" which is using a custom template.
This page is supposed to be called like so:
`www.site.com/user/<ID>`

Is it possible to get the ID segment of the URL programmatically?
The goal is to show the details of the user that belongs to the given ID.

When testing, that part of the URL is always removed.
If I request the URL
`www.site.com/user/123`
the page is redirected to:
`www.site.com/user`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have exactly the same thing happening. Posting an answer if you have it would be great for future searchers. TIA

Comment: @mpdaly the author has accepted an answer below already, see the answer with the big green checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that needed here, first add a new rewrite rule and second register the custom query variable.

So in your **functions.php**

```
/**
 * Add custom rewrite rule.
 *
 * NOTE: the `user_id` will be registered in the `query_vars` filter below. 
 */
add_action( 'init', function() {
   add_rewrite_rule(
      '^user/([0-9]+)/?',
      'index.php?pagename=user&user_id=$matches[1]',
      'top'
   );
} );


/**
 * Register custom query variables.
 */
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
   $vars[] = 'user_id';

   return $vars;
} );
```

And inside your template you can then access the user ID by calling `get_query_var( 'user_id' )`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't get it to work, and am still experiencing the unwanted redirect. If you had any tips for debugging this then they'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try re-saving the Permalinks at least twice?

Comment: Hi there! I implemented this solution and it worked. I completely forgot to provide feedback and express my gratitude here, so thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's all working now (I should say back working, because it is a 10-year-old site built be someone else with severe rot, and seemed to pre-date this technique: no idea how it used to work in an ancient version of WP!).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should be able to call the query var by:

```
get_query_var('user');
```

if this does not work, then "user" is not the registered query var. You can debug by dumping $wp_query and pin pointing the var / key.

```
global $wp_query;
```

Comment: Hi @Jhonatan Villena! Thks for the reply. Not sure if we are on the same page. My problem is when I try to access this URL: www.site.com/user/123 the browser redirects to: www.site.com/user. Is there a way of preventing this from happening?